# How to create replica set in mongoDb new version above 6.0 in windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication, database-replication, multiserver

how to create replication in mongoDb (node js) in latest version.

i was trying mongodb documentation
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

i used this command to run instance as replication:

```
mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs0 --dbpath="C:\data\db0"
```

then in `mongosh`

run `rs.initiate()` command and getting error as replica set not found

Comment: What kind of problem did you get?

Comment: i was using command "rs.initiate()", again getting error "replica set not found"

Comment: you should provide all information you have

Comment: Are you sure, you connected to the correct Mongo Database? Did you start multiple MongoDB instances on your machine?

Comment: What is the output of the `mongod` command?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, i only have one mongoDB instance, i want create multiple instance using replica set, mongod command does not retunrs with any error.
could you please let me know how can i run multiple instance.
thanks

Comment: "one mongoDB instance" and "using replica set" is contradicting (unless you use replica set with just one member, which is pointless). So again, what is the output of `mongod`? How do you start the other replica set members? Maybe have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Comment: When I am downloading MongoDB of the below 5.0 version, in mongo shell rs.initiate() command runs correctly. but when I am using MongoDB 6.0 rs.initiate() throwing error: This node is not running on replica set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download mongosh new version and in mongo shell try to run these commands

```
rs.initiate();
rs.conf();
```